# Dynamic Array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to create an array of strings but I keep getting an error.

Can you help me figure out what's wrong with this code?

```
    int size;
    scanf("%d",&size);
    char** arr;
    arr=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*size);
```

Comment: What error is reported?

Comment: Breaks out of the debbuger.

Comment: What platform are you using?  Name of IDE and compiler?

Comment: you are only creating memory for pointers to strings but not the strings.. can you post all your code

Comment: @CherubimAnand, agreed, however the code posted itself doesn't look wrong, it could do with some checking before the allocation to make sure the size is > 0.

Comment: @SPlatten agreed. I asked for his entire code to know whether he is allocating memory for strings or not

Comment: Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Apart from error checking, the 4 lines of code you show should work — but there's a lot of ways things could go wrong after these lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use array of `n` number of pointers to char. Then use a loop to allocate space for those.

```
int n, size;
scanf("%d %d", &n, &size);
char *arr[n];
for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ){
    arr[i] = malloc( size * sizeof(char) );
}
```